# Why cstdio includes stdio.h?

Tags: c++, include, std, libc, libstdc++

I've found std lib header `cstdio` ([libcxx implementation line 100](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/tags/RELEASE_34/final/include/cstdio)) to include `stdio.h`. So now clang (using via `libclang` - C API) diagnostics reports that stdio.h is not found (in some device specific environment which i'm configuring). It seems to be include paths problem (-I) and i'm just trying to understand dependencies and the reason and build correct includes path.

Comment: The `<cstdio>` header file is just a wrapper into the standard `std` namespace of the `<stdio.h>` header file. Exactly *how* that wrapping is done doesn't matter, but it's easy to just `#include <stdio.h>` inside instead of rewriting the whole file.

Comment: ok, that's clear. Does it mean libcxx requires libc installed on the device (afaik stdio.h is libc header) and including libc include paths for the app that uses libc++?

Comment: Much of the functionality of C has to be available in C++. Exactly how that is done is implementation-specific, but, again, why rewrite when the support is already there in the C library?

Comment: ok, now i understand libcxx is not standalone and libc headers should be available to make libcxx working too,

Comment: That depends on which part of libcxx you want, of course - `<vector`, `<algorithm>`, `<limits>` and so on typically don't depend on libc.